# Why is EMF induced in a rotating ring?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

It's obvious that a metallic ring rotating in a magnetic field will have an emf $\epsilon$
induced across it. using a combination of the centripetal force and the Lorentz force, this makes sesne. BUt I'm unable to explain it using faraday's alw. The only idea I can think of is drawing an imaginary radius vector from the centre to the ring, and saying that the area swept out by that changes with time.

Comment: Can you explain what axis the ring is rotating around, and what direction the magnetic field points in? Is the magnetic field static?

Comment: My bad. The field is static and into the screen, the ring rotates clockwise on the plane of teh screen.

Comment: And the ring lies in the plane of the page?

Comment: yes, it does...

Answer (score 1):

In the OP's setup, with the ring in the plane of the page and rotating clockwise, and the magnetic field pointing into the page, a unit positive test charge in the ring will experience a magnetic force given by the product of its velocity, which is *tangential* to the ring, and the magnetic field. This magnetic force will point radially outward. For a negative charge, the force will be radially inward.

There will be no emf. The emf around the ring is given by

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E} = \int (E + v \times B) \cdot \mathrm{d}s
\end{equation}

where the integral is taken along a given path (*e.g.* a loop that coincides with the ring) and $v$ is the velocity of the wire at the point where the integrand is evaluated. Since $v \times B$ is perpendicular to $\mathrm{d}s$, the integrand vanishes.

This result, $\mathcal{E} = 0$, coincides with that given by Faraday's law.

Note that the "centripetal force" mentioned by the OP is irrelevant; the charges in the ring must accelerate in the radial direction in order to stay in the ring, but the Lorentz force only depends on velocity.

Answer (score 0):

in Faraday's law the area is a vector, so the area changes fom parallel to B to perpendicular to B.